# If $G$ is a finite group where every non-identity element is generator of $G$, what is the order of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $G$ is a finite group where every non-identity element is generator of $G$, what is the order of $G$?

I know that the order of $G$ must be prime, but I'm not sure how to go about proving this from the problem statement.

Any hints on where to start?

Comment: Hint: Assume not, and consider a generator $g$ and then look at $g^n$ where $n$ is a proper divisor of the order of the group.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the order of $G$ was not prime and let $n$ be the order of $G$. Then for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ which divide $n$, the subgroup generated by $g^k$ has only $n/k$ elements while $G$ has $n$ elements.

Therefore, the subgroup generated by $g^k$ cannot equal $G$.

Therefore, the order of $G$ must be prime.

---

Should my proof go something like this?

Comment: Yes, that looks good (though you should remember to point out that $n/k$ is only smaller than $n$ when $k < n$ but that is a minor detail).

Comment: To probably make things even easier, you could also begin by remarking that the group *must* be abelian (in fact, cyclic).

Answer (score 0):

Using Cauchy's Theorem: let $p$ be a prime dividing $|G|$. Then $G$ has an element $g$ of order $p$. Apparently this element $g$ generates $G$. Hence $|G|=p$.

Comment: Alternatively: By the classification of finite simple groups, the only abelian ones are those of prime order (and this group will clearly be simple).

Comment: Tobias what is your point?

Comment: That using Cauchy for this is overkill (though obviously not as much as the classification would be).

Comment: (it was meant as a joke, btw, not as an actual criticism of the answer).

Comment: OK - but I do not deem using Cauchy as an overkill, matter of taste maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Since every nonidentity element of $G$ is a generator, $G$ is generated by some element $x$;  hence $G$ is cyclic.  If the order of $G$ is composite, say $|G|=p r$, where $p, r >1$, then there exists a nonidentity element $x^p$ that does not generate $G$, a contradiction.  Thus, the order of $G$ must be a prime.